# Value bringing back Null

Tags: java, android

I have a social app that builds a list of cars for users.  Each user builds their own list. When I click on a listview item to link car data with dealership data I bring back a null value in the below code, when in fact I'm trying to bring back an integer value that's saved in a sqlite table.  My code is below.  I can add more code if needed.

```
private Integer d;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_cars);
    Car c = new Car();
    this.d = c.getD1();
    Log.d("Car","Car: " + d); //<---this brings back Null
    ...
    ...
}

public class Car implements Serializable {

public static final String TAG = "Car";
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7406082437623008161L;

private long Id;
private String mk;
private String modl;
private Integer d1;
private USER xUser;


public Car() {
    this.mk=null;
    this.modl=null;
    this.d1=null;



}


public Car(String make, String model,Integer d1) {
    super();

    this.mk = make;
    this.modl = model;
    this.d1 = d1;




}


public long getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(long xId) {
    this.Id = xId;
}


public String getMake(){return mk;}
public void setMake(String make) {this.make = mk;}

public String getModel(){return modl;}
public void setModel(String model) {this.model = modl;}

public Integer getD1(){return d1;}
public void setD1(Integer d1) {this.d1 = d1;}

public USER getUser() {
    return xUser;
}
public void setUser(USER yUser) {
    this.xUser = yUser;
}


}
```

Comment: Where do you call `c.setD1`? If the default value in `Car` for `d` is null, then this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I got it working by using intent.putExtra in the previous activity which feeds my current one.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting d to `c.getD1()` it is probably being set to null because c is equal to a `new Car()` so therefore none of the values in c are filled in. So in order for d to not be null you would have to call `c.setD1(someValue)`, unless in the Car class d1 has a default value, but with the code you provided I cant know for sure, but I am guessing you have not given it a default value, and this is why you are getting null.

Comment: How would I bring back the value of attribute D1, which has data in the sqlite table? Do I need to do something with Intent in order to pass data from sqlite back to the listview?  Thanks.

Comment: please post the full car class

Answer (score 0):

The default value of type Integer is null.If you don't use set function such as setD1 when you create a new Object of Car,the value d1 will be null.Then in your main class the value d will be null.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a construction for Car. You should assign default value for all values in order prevent "null". Because of you assign new construct set all value to be null. It will get null for all values in car class.

```
public Car() {
    this.mk="";
    this.modl="";
    this.d1=0;
}
```

this is the place causing null. 
    **Car c = new Car();** --> construction assign value to null 
    this.d = c.getD1(); --> assign null to **this.d**
 you should assign 
c.setD1(integer); --> prevent null

Comment: I don't think that is correct.  Setting it to 0 or null is just going to return 0 or null.  What's the difference to setting it to 0?  It still returns 0 (even though it has an integer value in database).